# Using existing MySQL databases in MVC 5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC. I am going to develop MVC version of an asp.net site. The site is/will be backed by multiple MySQL databases. The data in databases is populated by an other process, which is out of my control, hence there is no chance to modify schemas any way.
My Problem is how to design entities to work with mysql stored procedures using db first approach? I am saying stored procedures, because I am not going to use all columns of targeted tables as they are, but some time I will do some calculation job at database side. Hence I am limited to use stored procedures! An other problem is designing DbContext classes for such scenario. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what did you find in Google?

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing entity framework with MVC.  I think you can use EF with MySQL, I would be tempted to go with NHibernate

Comment: @ScottSelby I googled a lot, but couldn't find any comprehensive article!

Comment: I used EF with MySQL before. You'll need to download ADO.NET driver for MySQL from Oracle. I did not use it with stored procedures though.

Comment: Look at the following links. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html (includes 
http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/ and http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)